How to Prove Ownership of a New Address to an Exchange?
I am planning to withdraw some sats from my exchange (Gemini) to my Trezor one. But they seem to have a very strict withdrawal SOP that requires me to prove the ownership of a public address.
The problems, as I see, are twofold

my trezor wallet has a few sats, but the specific address I created is brand new and I never received any fund there
I can send a few sats from my trezor device to the exchange, as a small deposit test, but I do not see a way to control the origin address. I mean, is not my trezor device just the collection of all addresses? I can receive in any of them, but can I send from a specific one of them?

So what's the way out here? Does Trezor 1 support this feature? Or have to resort to something else?

You're in luck in using a Trezor, which actually makes this somewhat manageable.
The functionality you're looking for is called Coin Control - where you can specify which existing UTXOs to spend from, hence controlling the address the funds originate from in your deposit transaction to Gemini.
You would have to have enough BTC in some address to be able to first send it to the address you wish to prove ownership of.
Then, you can use the coin control features in Trezor Suite, or connect your Trezor to other wallets that offer similar functionality - Electrum, for example.
